# Deploying Storm topology with Spark dependency

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, slf4j, apache-storm

I'm trying to deploy a Storm topology (version 1.0.0) with a Spark dependency (version 1.6.1). That topology works normally using Local Cluster, but not submitting it to a cluster. I know that Spark and Storm needs the libs related with log4j. So, if the pom file is modified to:

```
 <!-- Apache Spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

This error occurs:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.setLevel(Lorg/apache/log4j/Level;)V
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:75) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:75) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:75) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1988) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1979) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:266) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at ufrn.imd.engsoft.storm.SentimentAnalyserBolt.prepare(SentimentAnalyserBolt.java:106) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__8226$fn__8239.invoke(executor.clj:795) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__554.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_65]
2016-04-22 00:29:06.285 o.a.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Worker died")
```

And without any exclusions in the Spark dependency this error occurs:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39) ~[log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:75) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1988) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1979) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:266) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:1.6.1]
at ufrn.imd.engsoft.storm.SentimentAnalyserBolt.prepare(SentimentAnalyserBolt.java:106) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__8226$fn__8239.invoke(executor.clj:795) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__554.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:49) ~[log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
... 18 more
```

In both cases above the Storm dependency is the following:

```
<!-- Apache Storm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

The Storm folder contains these jars:

```
- log4-api-2.1
- log4j-core-2.1
- log4j-over-sl4j-1.6.6
- log4j-sl4j-impl-2.1
- sl4j-api-1.7.7
- sl4j-log4j12
```

Maybe the Spark being able to get the jars above could solve that problem, but I didn't find clues to do that. Somebody could help me with any idea about how to resolve that problem?

Thanks (:!

Answer (score 0):

`log4j` only defines an logging interface and `log4j-over-slf4j` and `slf4j-log4j12` and concrete implementations of this interface. As Storm finds both implementations, is does not know which one to use (in the case you do not exclude anything).

In your "exclude" case however, you exclude both, the interface and concrete implementation, so you get the error about the missing interface. Try to exclude only the implementation but not the interface.

Comment: I tried exclude only the implementations, but the same error continues. `2016-04-25 08:24:05.216 STDIO [ERROR] SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError.
2016-04-25 08:24:05.218 STDIO [ERROR] SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
2016-04-25 08:24:05.221 o.a.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39) ~[log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]`. I believe that the libs from storm folder should be used.

Comment: Maybe the pom is correct, because I'm submitting the topology to a remote storm cluster, as consequence the libs from storm folder is being used. However, for some reason the Spark (local mode) is not utilizing that libs. I also tried to use a spark cluster.